# Spending limits on polygon pending?

Tags: gnosis-safe

Any dev know why this task haven't been deployed yet ? I saw that the BSC equivalent was done but not on polygon, any reason why ? : https://github.com/gnosis/safe-react/issues/2991#issue-1051940887

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the issue it was a matter of prioritization and is planned for the future. It is not just deploying the contract. Before the team enabled this feature for the users it has to be tested which takes time.

In general feel free to ask these questions on the issues or the [Safe discord](https://chat.gnosis-safe.io), as this is not really a question for this StackExchange.